Finding the Electric Field at a Point From a Non-uniformly Charged Disk

The attached image gives a basic idea of the geometry at play, but essentially I have a non-uniformly charged disk, the surface charge density of which is given by σ(r) = Cr, C is a constant and r is measured from the center of the disk. I want to find the resulting electric field at point P, which is some distance x away from the center of the disk. Calculating the field from a uniform disk isn't so bad, but the answers I've been finding so far are just making no sense. I'm sure I just can't figure out how to set the integral up correctly. Any help is appreciated.

I'm sure I just can't figure out how to set the integral up correctly. You need to show some effort and explain what problem you’re having. The calculation is a minor modification to the uniform-surface-density case.

The answers I've been finding so far are just making no sense. You haven’t said what those answers are, or why you think they don’t make sense. Perhaps they’re simply wrong.

We know that the electric field contribution of each infinitesimal piece of the disk is given by $k \mathrm{d}q/(x^2 + r^2)$. What's $\mathrm{d}q$? Well, it's going to be the surface charge density times an infinitesimal area, i.e., $Cr \cdot r \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$. Now we note that in the vertical direction, the electric field components from all the infinitesimal pieces are going to cancel by symmetry. Therefore, we will only be left with the horizontal components and if you recall from the uniform case, we will need to multiply by a factor of  $x/\sqrt{x^2 + r^2}$ to account for this effect. Then we have \begin{align} \vec{E} &=  k\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R\frac{Cr}{x^2 + r^2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + r^2}} r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta ~\vec{v}, \end{align} where $\vec{v}$ denotes the unit vector from the center of the disk to $P$. This is a pretty nasty integration and it yields the solution \begin{align} \vec{E} = \frac{\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{R}{x}\right) \sqrt{x^{2} + R^{2}} - R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + R^{2}}} \vec{v},
\end{align} where $\operatorname{arsinh}(x) = \ln \left(x+{\sqrt {x^{2}+1}}\right)$. A couple of sanity checks can be performed at this point. We note that if $R \to 0$, the electric field also goes to zero. This checks out because we are shrinking the disk down to a point and the density at the origin is zero. Further, the density increases linearly with respect to $r$. Therefore, we expect that if we let $R \to \infty$, the electric field should blow up at $P$. Indeed, for large $R$, we find that the magnitude of the electric field at $P$ is approximately $\ln(2R/x)$.
